# KDE Applications are changed to too big interface

Tags: kde-plasma

I use Arch Linux (i3-wm) with KDE. All kde apps are changed to big after `pacman -Syu`.

- KDE Frameworks: 5.87.0
- Qt version: 5.15.2

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by changing DPI to 92.
[image]